# How can I write this recursive Haskell function

Tags: function, haskell, recursion

Task:

> Write a recursive Haskell function, which get 2 ordered list and the function decide that each of them element are equal or not (if one of them are same the function value is `False`).
>
> For example:
>
> - `myfunction [1..5] [6..10] == True`
> - `myfunction [1..5] [5..10] == False`

I cannot use the `elem` function.
I can use recursion and case apart choice.

Function type:

```
myfunction :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
```

I tried something like this:

```
myfunction :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> Bool
myfunction [] list = True
myfunction list [] = True
myfunction (x:xs) (y:ys)
    | x == y = False
    | xs == myfunction ???????? = False
```

But it does not works...

Comment: you are aware that you never use the `<` function, a hint would be assert that just `x` is in the second list (or not) and then do that recursively for all other `xs`

Comment: What is the logic of your last line?  What is `disjoint` and where did it come from and why does it only need to consider the second list in isolation?

Comment: I edited it, it is not disjoint, sorry. I don't know the logic thats why I ask for help.

Comment: Please provide one of: compiling code with an explanation of what part of its behavior you don't understand, or the error message the compiler gives when provided with the exact code in the post and why you don't understand the compiler error.  This post doesn't contain either of those.

Comment: OK, if you don't know the logic then why did you write the last line?  What is it you want to happen at that point?   Think about it some, this line is the core of your problem.

Comment: I don't know how should I call recursively the funtion to compare each of elements.

Comment: I though it about 3 hours... Any useful help?

Comment: for `myfunction (x:xs) (y:ys)`, either `x==y`, or `x<y`, or `x>y`. If `x<y`, we know that for all `z` in `ys` it is guaranteed to be `x<z` too.

Comment: in which case we need not worry about `x` anymore -- can just ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(This answer is really just the comments you already received in answer form.) You'd implement it as follows:

```
myFunction [] _ = True
myFunction _ [] = True
myFunction (x : xs) (y : ys) = case compare x y of
  LT -> myFunction xs (y : ys)
  EQ -> False
  GT -> myFunction (x : xs) ys
```

This works because if `x` is smaller than `y`, `x` is also smaller (and therefore not equal, which is what we really wanted to know) than any element in `ys`. That means we can ignore it and check the rest of the lists. When `x` is greater than `y`, it's the other way around.

Comment: Can we assume that each argument consists of unique values? That doesn't seem clear in the question.

Comment: @chepner: It should work either way. (Unless I'm missing something.)

Comment: I'm probably misinterpreting the problem. It seemed to me the goal was to detect any duplicates between the two arguments.